# What is Custom XML Data in MS Word Document - Office 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, xml, microsoft-office-2013

While inspecting a Word Document originally created in Office 2003 but opened and edited in Office 2013, the results show 'Custom XML Data' as an item that can be removed from the document.

What is 'Custom XML Data" and what information it usually holds?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: .docx format used to have the ability for the user to store their own xml data.  If you have not stored this it's likely it's just picking up the empty placeholder segment.  It's harmless.  If you want a more detailed explanation look [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/custom-xml-data/a916a967-7fc6-4399-afdb-7b6e07d5ccee)

Comment: I was going to add an answer about inspecting the docx for custom xml by changing the extension to zip. However the link Ramhound gave above have all those info and more. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> Like the false positive security alert, this is not something to be concerned about.
>
> A little background will help: Documents that are saved in the .docx format actually consist almost entirely of XML (which stands for eXtensible Markup Language). Most of that XML is standardized to mark things like headings and tables.
>
> In the initial release of Word 2007, there was also the ability to include special ("custom") pieces of XML for whatever purpose was desired. That capability wasn't used very much, but when it was used it was usually by add-ins or macros, not by end users.
>
> In 2009 a company named i4i won a [patent lawsuit](http://www.pcworld.com/article/170148/microsoft_word_xml.html) claiming that Microsoft infringed its patent, and the court required Microsoft to remove the custom XML feature from Word. Further, from that date onward, any version of Word that opened a document in which custom XML was already present would be required to remove the custom XML from the file.
>
> So the bottom line is that **custom XML in a Word document is not a security risk** to anyone. It's just a very expensive headache for Microsoft and for anyone who might write an add-in that would benefit from using the forbidden custom XML.

–by Jay Freedman in this [Microsoft Answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/custom-xml-data/a916a967-7fc6-4399-afdb-7b6e07d5ccee), courtesy of [Ramhound's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1235715/what-is-custom-xml-data-in-ms-word-document-office-2013#comment1809430_1235715)